# java printf help needed

Tags: java, printf

```
public class Format
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.printf("%30s|%30s","Organization","Number of users");
        System.out.printf("%30s|%30s","Arcot","100");
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
          Organization|               Number of users                          Arcot|                           100
```

Why is the 2nd row out of alignment? The word "Arcot" is not given enough padding, although the word "100" is. I'm sorry, this text window applies its own formatting, it is not showing what I have pasted as the output. You may need to run the code to see the output obtained.

Comment: format the "output" as code, than you can easily show the effect ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try these.

```
System.out.println(String.format("%30s|%30s","Organization","Number of users"));
    System.out.println(String.format("%30s|%30s","Arcot","100"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("%30s|%30s\n","Organization","Number of users");
System.out.printf("%30s|%30s\n","Arcot","100");
```

You have to insert `\n` issue a newline character end of first parameter of `printf`.

More info about [using escape character](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/9577.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected:

```
System.out.printf("%30s|%30s%n","Organization","Number of users");
System.out.printf("%30s|%30s%n","Arcot","100");
```

results in

```
              Organization|               Number of users
                     Arcot|                           100
```

on my machine. You didn't add line feeds. `%n` is the preferred notation in format Strings.